# Flickering horizontal line while scrolling

Tags: drivers, nvidia, mate, ubuntu-mate, flicker

I have got a really weird problem. 
When I scroll a web page, look through images really fast with right arrow held or render something with OpenGL on high fps, I have got this flickering horizontal line at the center of the screen or a little bit lower. It feels like the system cannot handle redrawing of large amounts of changing pixels, change buffers quickly or something along those lines.

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 MATE, 410 NVIDIA driver and apart from that the system is clean. I can't figure out how to fix this and why this is happening. Oh, and one last thing - I have got GeForce GTX Titan Black, maybe this has something to do with the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, looks like I figured out how to fix this. Maybe it will help someone.

1. Go to `NVIDIA X Server Settings` application.
2. Choose `X Server Display Configuration`.
3. Click `Advanced`.
4. Check `Force Full Composition Pipeline`.
5. `Apply`.
6. Probably restart the system.

I have tried every single option suggested here on stackoverflow with `compizconfig-settings-manager`, `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`, e.t.c. but noting seemed to work for my issue.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks! Tbh I was surprised I even found any results with "linux line in middle of screen while scrolling" lol

Comment: @MattCorby I'm glad it helped. It's a temporary solution though, you'll have to do this routine from time to time. At least on my system it is.

Comment: Yes I have to do this everytime I reboot. You can create an X config file through NVIDIA X server settings but I haven't figured out where i'm supposed to put it yet so that it loads on startup.

Comment: This solved the issue, but after I saved it and rebooted only the second monitor was working, I had to delete Xorg settings and it started working again but I had the same problem again.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by setting window manager to *Marco (Compton GPU compositor)*.

[image]

See [this link](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/browser-page-refresh-horizontal-flickering-lines/8579) for more information.